# How can I show that an argument or proposition is valid through logic proof sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I know the logic of proof sequence as I solved many proof problems, I now have one that has been taken my attention for a couple of days and as easy as it may look, I don't seem able to simplify the first hypothesis of the problem even I tried many ways.
So,the question is, How can I simplify the first hypothesis?

Given:

1. ~[~( A => B) => C ] => D
2. ~B
3. ~C
4. ~D

Show true for ~A

Comment: It appears that they are trying to get you to realize that $A \implies \text{ false }$ is equivalent to $\lnot A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you know, you should prove that contrapositve is an okay step.

Then,

1. $\neg [\neg( A \to B) \to C ] \to D$ becomes  $\neg  D\to  \neg  \neg[\neg ( A \to B) \to C ]$ by contrapositive.
2. $\neg  D\to  \neg  \neg[\neg ( A \to B) \to C ]$  , $\neg D$ becomes  $\neg  \neg[\neg ( A \to B) \to C ]$ by modus ponens.
3. $\neg  \neg[\neg ( A \to B) \to C ]$ becomes $\neg ( A \to B) \to C$ by negation elimination.
4. $\neg ( A \to B) \to C$ becomes  $\neg C \to \neg \neg( A \to B)$ by contrapositive.
5. $\neg C \to \neg \neg( A \to B)$ , $\neg C$ becomes $\neg \neg( A \to B)$ by modus ponens
6. $\neg \neg( A \to B)$ becomes $A \to B$ by negation elimination.
7. $A \to B$ becomes $\neg B \to \neg A$  by contrapositive.
8. By modus ponens again, we are finished and are left with $\neg A$.